# Redirect all subdomains except www to main domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I want to redirect all subdomains except www to https://www.example.com in .htaccess, how can I do this? All subdomains can be accessed.

I only want to redirect the subdomains, not inner pages on the main domain.

Examples: (Should redirect)

- hello.domain.com
- test.example.domain.com
- www.hello.sub.domain.com

Examples of where not to redirect:

- www.domain.com/hello-world
- www.domain.com

Current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.dk$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.domain.dk/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started. Anything apart from www.mydomain.com will be redirected to www.example.com.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

**Edit:**

Remember that it's the .htaccess in your subdomain folder, or _wildcard_domain.com that you will have to create or edit for this to work.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. By the way, the subdomains are accessable. And testing in incognito mode.

Comment: Have a go using http://httpstatus.io to test - this won't be affected by caching.

Comment: Another question, what about pages such as https://www.example.com/hello-world - would that also be redirected, because that's not what I want.

Comment: The website returns 200 status code and 0 redirects.

Comment: Maybe ask a new question about the hello-world case. As for this particular issue, what exactly do you have in your htaccess file now?

Comment: Got anything else I can try?

Comment: Just figured out I was editing the wrong .htaccess file. I should edit the one under _wildcard_domain.dk folder, then it worked. Please clarify it in your answer for other people with same question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your rule redirects **sub.example.com** to **http://www.sub.example.com** .